# Python - Having trouble opening a file with spaces

Tags: python, filenotfoundexception

So I am attempting to open multiple files within the "subnet folder" folder. However, it is not allowing me to open a specific file that contains spaces in it

```
for filename in os.listdir(pathlib.Path.cwd() / "Subnet folder"):
    f = open(filename, 'r', encoding="ISO-8859-1")
```

This is the error I receive:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '10.181.136.0  24.csv'
```

The file is most definitely there so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `os.listdir` returns the names of the contained elements in the path, but **without the path** itself.

Comment: are they in the same folder as your script? in the same leve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spaces aren't the problem here; relative paths are.

`os.listdir`  yields only the names of the files, not a path relative to your current working directory. If you want to open the file, you need to use the relative path.

```
d = pathlib.Path.cwd() / "Subnet folder"
for filename in os.listdir(d):
    f = open(d / filename, 'r', encoding="ISO-8859-1")
```

Note that you don't actually need to use `cwd` here, as both `listdir` and `open` already interpret relative paths against your current working directory.

```
for filename in os.listdir("Subnet folder"):
    f = open(os.path.join("Subnet folder", filename), ...)
```

Or, change your working directory first. Then, the file name itself will be a valid relative path for `open`.

```
os.chdir("Subnet folder)
for filename in os.listdir():
    f = open(filename, ...)
```

Finally, you could avoid `os.listdir` altogether, because if the `Path` object refers to a directory, you can iterate over its contents directly. This iteration yields a series of `Path` instances, each of which has an `open` method that can be used in place of the ordinary `open` function.

```
for filename in (pathlib.Path.cwd() / "Subnet Folder").iterdir():
    f = filename.open(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to add `Subnet Folder` in front of the file name. You could use `os`

```
import os
for filename in os.listdir(pathlib.Path.cwd() / "Subnet folder"):
    f = open(os.path.join("Subnet folder", filename), 'r', encoding="ISO-8859-1")
```

Answer (score 1):

The `filename` ends up being relative to your CWD, so you want to do something like

```
folder = pathlib.Path.cwd() / "Subnet folder"
for filename in os.listdir(folder):
    f = open(folder / filename, 'r', encoding="ISO-8859-1")
```